# mobile applications for IOS and Android

Tags: mobile-application

I want to develop an app for ios and android for a customer project
Can i use android studio to develop the app first later use the available plugins to make it work on IOS
or use a framework like cordova
which is best

Comment: Which is best depends on so many things that you have not mentioned.  Do you want native features? What type of experience do you have?  There are so many things that could determine this.  I only asked 2 out of several questions

Comment: If you want native features, then cordova will not be easy.  People that are really good can make these web based apps look like a native app, but you will find out that it is not the easiest to match the native style.   Plus I don't think all the plugins are available with cordova.  They have some.   There are also 3rd party tools to make multi platform apps but many cost money.  You could instead make one app for each platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i am naive in mobile app development (just a week old) so have no idea what to use and what not to use, just figuring out.As per the features it is similar to data subscription, cancellation etc

Comment: If you have never made apps before or you have never done web development,  then you will not like cordova.  For someone just starting out, the native development using xcode and android studio will be much easier.  As you progress you can try out some other things.  That's my suggestion.  It really depends on your level of experience.

Comment: thank you for your valued suggestion